# How to remove that wierd line on the side?

Tags: 16.04, unity

On unity I have this weird like showing up as the image shows:
[image: Screenshot showing the mysterious line]

It seems that the frame that is shown when the side menu is being revealed or the dash menu is shown when I press the `super`(`windows`) key. Also I have no idea how to reproduce it. Is somehow a way to refresh and make the whole window manager to rerender without the need to logout?

In an attempt to hide it I locked my screen and logged in back again.

I suspect that Virtualbox is the one causing it.

## Edit 1

So far I figured out that the line is shown when I click multiple times on an icon on the sidebar. I guess it is a leftover on how the windows that the applications that is represented by the icon are shown.

Comment: Does bringing up dash make it disappear?

Comment: Dash appears and disappears normally.

Comment: Log into another account (create another account if you need to). The line/box will probably NOT show up. If that's correct, log back into your own account, and disable the extensions/software that loads up the various icons displayed in your top task bar, log out, log in, and see if the lines/box shows. If NOT, then one of your extensions/software is the cause. Lastly, make sure the Conky is not causing your problem. Report back.

Comment: I did further investigation to display more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved via following theese steps:

1. Press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`
2. Login with your user credentials
3. Type `DISPLAY=:0 unity --replace`

And you are good to go!